# To reduce the perception of slowness of my HTML based presentation, I want to pre-load the next slide. What's a good way of doing this?

Tags: jquery, html, optimization

While they are watching the first slide I would like to load the second one up in the background and simply 'slide' it into view when requested by the user. Otherwise they have to watch a loading bar or spinner which always receives complaints. How can this be done properly?

Also, would it be possible for me to keep all the slides available 'somewhere' so they can just as easily browse back or would I need to set a cut off and 'destroy' some of them to prevent the browser from lagging down? I'm not sure how that works or what my limitations are.

**UPDATE:** The slides are simply HTML but most contain audio and a few video. I am assuming that the best approach would be to re-request the audio and video for a slide as it gains focus but the HTML and potential images are what I want to be already loaded when they browse forward. There could be 20 slides, there could be 200 slides. I doubt anything greater in most cases.

We don't have to have it save all the previously viewed slides but I at least want to be able to pre-load the next one.

Comment: How many slides are there and what kind of data do they contain?

Comment: E.g., are they images or what? You'll need to provide much more information.

Comment: @Pekka @T.J. Crowder (see update)

Comment: you *could* experiment with loading slides into `iframe`s, but for big slides and multimedia stuff, this can easily overload the client PC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would fall back on AJAX for this type of project, assuming your slides are content-rich. Once you display a slide, there's no reason I see that you can't asynchronously load the HTML for the next slide into a hidden `<div>...</div>` and simply show that `<div>...</div>` when ready and fetch the 3rd slide.

Check out [jQuery's .ajax() function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) if you're not already familiar with it

This should get your images and text loaded, and you can then trigger the loading of the audio/video at the correct time.

Comment: Thanks, do you think the browser would suffer if I left all loaded slides available in divs once they are loaded? I mean would the browser lag out at all once I hit like 50 divs for example?

Comment: That would certainly depend on the amount of content. I would give this a try and if you suffer from any type of latency, you could keep only 3 slides "on-hand" at a time. The slide you're looking at, and the slide before and after it. All you need is three divs ("prev", "current", and "next"). simply keep "prev" and "next hidden. When you advance slides, set "prev" with the innerHTML of "current", set "current" to the innerHTML of "next" and populate "next" with your ajax fetch data.

Comment: In thinking about this further, you could even create an array with 50 slots (or however many slides you have) and you can pre-populate the array with the HTML for each slide. It'll take place behind the scenes with ajax.. this way the HTML is on-call all of the time, and you can just use THAT html to populate your "prev", "current", and "next" `div` items

Comment: I'll try something like that, I wonder if the browser would slow down because of all that HTML?

Comment: As long as you're loading asynchronously, and not displaying all of the HTML right away - you shouldn't see any sort of issue. I've been wrong before though, so if you do - just use AJAX to load the "next" or "prev" slides as needed.